# Understand if the demographics percentages on a cohort of users are in line with my population demographics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

Suppose, my general user population stats are

female - 65 %
male - 25 %
unreported - 10 %

I have a cohort of users of interest who clicked on an ad campaign and the demographics proportion is

female - 60 %
male - 35 %
unreported - 10 %

What statistical test can I do to figure out if these proportions are in line with my population proportion?
I am a stats newbie, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), which has information for new users. Do you mean 5% unreported in your cohort of interest?

Comment: How many individuals are there in your cohort?